# wavelet for numerical partial differential equations

Tags: pde, ode, wavelet

Is there a good introduction into wavelet Galerkin schemes for numerical partial (and ordinary) differential equations?

Answer (score 1):

Some good references can be found on Gregory Beylkin's homepage [here](http://amath.colorado.edu/faculty/beylkin/papers/index.html).

[G. Beylkin, On wavelet-based algorithms for solving differential equations
Chapter in the book  Wavelets: Mathematics and Applications, CRC Press, 1994](http://amath.colorado.edu/faculty/beylkin/papers/BEYLKI-1994b.pdf)

[G. Beylkin and J. M. Keiser, On the Adaptive Numerical Solution of Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations in Wavelet Bases,  Journal of Computational Physics, vol. 132, pp. 233-259, 1997](http://amath.colorado.edu/faculty/beylkin/papers/BEY-KEI-1997.pdf)

[B. Alpert, G. Beylkin, D. Gines,  and  L. Vozovoi, Adaptive Solution of Partial Differential Equations in Multiwavelet Bases,  Journal of Computational Physics,  v. 182, pp. 149-190, 2002](http://amath.colorado.edu/faculty/beylkin/papers/A-B-G-V-2002.pdf)

Comment: It is best to provide context to each of the specific references and why you recommend them in particular.

Answer (score -1):

Thorsten Raasch has nice notes (well - in German) but also some more literature on his webpage here http://www.mathematik.uni-mainz.de/Members/raasch/juniorprof.-dr.-thorsten-raasch?set_language=en.

Comment: The website does not provide any literature.

Comment: Right - actually I don't know how to link to the right site directly. Just google "Raasch wavelet Skript"